# AngularJS ng-grid row.identity error

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm dynamically populating the columns to ng-grid. Grid populated the columns without any issues. But when I group the records based on one or more columns and then expanding the rows, I'm getting the below issue.

Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/ueoe?p0=row.entity.

Answer (score 0):

From ng-grid documentation:

groups [] Initial fields to group data by. Array of field names, not displayName.

so if you change

groups: 'Yourcolumname'

to

groups: ['Yourcolumname']

As no code is made available, it suppose to be the one that you might be facing.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm having dynamic columns. I'm not using columndefs or groups to define the columns.